# Что означает direction "1" canScrollVertically(1)?

Tags: java, android

На что влияет параметр 1 в recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что ответ на него легко находится в документации к методу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данная функция используется для того чтобы дать вам знать может ли список прокручиваться вниз или вверх или вы уже достигли одного из концов вашего списка:

```
direction = 1 для скрола вниз (bottom)
direction = -1 для скрола вверх (top)
```

если метод возвращает false, что означает, что вы достигли верхнего или нижнего уровня, зависит от направления. Вот например как можно перегнать все в переменную:

```
boolean canScrollDownMore = recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1);
```

Comment: Очень доходчиво, спасибо !